# Add easing to the rotation of an image on mouse position

Tags: image, rotation, position, mouse, easing

Sorry for the English.
I'm trying to add a "ease-out-elastic" movement of rotation, but I can not.
The code on which I am trying is http://jsfiddle.net/22Feh/5/.
Thanks

```
    
    var img = $('.image');
    if(img.length > 0){
    var offset = img.offset();
    function mouse(evt){
        var center_x = (offset.left) + (img.width()/2);
        var center_y = (offset.top) + (img.height()/2);
        var mouse_x = evt.pageX; var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
        var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
        var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90; 
        img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
        img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
        img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
        img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
    }
    $(document).mousemove(mouse);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easing calculations needs to be done using a timer. This can be complex, however there are many libraries out there that take care of this for you. Take a look at [GSAP](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/) for starters.

Using your code I've created the jsfiddle below. You can see that all I have done is replace your css code transform code with a TweenMax function and added the ease.

```
TweenMax.to(img, 1, {rotationZ:degree, ease:Elastic.easeOut});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Boolean/PNvgt/

Then if you want to take it a step further there is the GreenSock Draggable library.

http://www.greensock.com/draggable/